# fstab syntax for afp share with space and special characters?

Tags: afp, automount, autofs

I have a share on a netatalk server that exporting "Don's home" - I want to add to fstab so that it's handled by autofs as an indirect mount.

I've tried using %60 and %20, quoting, escaping with backslash, \40, \040, etc. Anyone know the syntax?

When there are no special characters this works fine:

```
server:/share dummy url net,automounted,url==afp://user:pass@server/share 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I've searched the whole Internet on this issue, and seems like you cannot automount points with spaces. I've tried all kinds of tricks on Yosemite to make myself sure.

(in the fstab file you can use "\040" between words which acts like a space )

However, you can use manual command to mount to such points, for SMB it will be:

```
mount_smbfs //user:password@server/share%20with%20spaces /Volumes/Network/Share\ With\ Spaces/
```

Probably this could exist in some [Automator](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT2488) script and get executed at a startup time, but this is not automount, of course. So I ended up with underscore characters in mount point names.